# Having problem assigning filepath as a variable in r

Tags: r

I want to assign a filepath as a variable that is copied in windows which can contain `\` symbol. I know I have to change it with one slash (`/`) or two backslashes (`\\`). However I want to write a function, it takes `"C:\Users\SysAdmin\Folder"` such a string and transform it to this form `"C:/Users/SysAdmin/Folder"`.

I heard that it is possible in python to add `r` at the beginning of the string, however I don't know how to figure it out in R.

Answer (score 0):

Place the file path in the clipboard and then in R:

```
mypath <- readClipboard()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This can fix the problem.